# Apply a feather to only one side of a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-effects

I'm tyring to apply a feather to a path, but I only one it applied on one area of the path.

I tried using the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) to select the anchors I wanted it applied around, that didn't help.

Is there a way to apply a feather (**Effects → Stylize → Feather**) to only one part of a path?

---

This is just an example, not the actual paths I'm using

I want the area in the dashed red line, to gradually fade in (using a feather was my initial thought)

[image: image mockup]

Comment: Any chance you could show what you are actually trying to achieve with such an effect?  There may be a different way to approach it entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is no method to apply any *effect* to a *portion* of an object. The Effect will pretty much always alter the entire object.

Using a gradient would probably be your best bet. Or an Opacity Mask.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but InDesign has an effect called 'Directional Feather', which can basicly feather an object from 4 sides independently.

[image]